# Adding a link between two already linked routers

Tags: networking

I have a fairly complex network setup at home, courtesy of living in a stupid house with stupid 13-inch thick solid walls. I have 4 routers connected, each broadcasting the same WiFi network. Only one of these has DHCP enabled, and that is connected to the Internet (so, everything is on the same subnet, *192.168.211.0/24* in my case).

Currently, the connection is very long, the Gateway (.1, VM superhub), connects to the Office (.2, Netgear WGR614v9), connects to the Kitchen (.3, Netgear WNR2200), connects to upstairs (.4, Netgear WNR1000v3).

I will soon have the opportunity to put in a link between the Gateway (.1), and the Kitchen (.3). So, once this link is in, should I leave the link in place between .1 and .2?

**P.S.** All the links are 100-MBit for the time being, and the connection from Upstairs (.4) needs strong access to the Office (.2).

**P.P.S** At some point in the future, I will be modifying the routers to 1-GBit Switches. Preferably a managed one, but that will probably be one of the router variety, which will probably include WiFi (or if not on-board, a few dedicated access-points). But a much faster network speed. But again, something that would give best performance and things to consider to avoid things like broadcast storms.

Comment: This isn't clear, it's not possible to answer your question with the provided information... Not sure how things are connected now, can you do a drawing or network diagram including all links and types of connections?

Comment: @acejavelin Well, its a great big daisy chain, out of port 1 on .1 runs a wire to port 1 on .2, then a wire runs from port 2 on .2 to port 1 on .3, then from port 2 on .3 to port 1 on .4. The internet comes into .1, but as it has a built-in modem, that's internal. No WAN port's are in use, each router has a few PC's hardwired, and then a bunch of WiFi devies around the house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't matter. There shouldn't be any conflicts, and it shouldn't affect the speeds. I would advise keeping it simple and using just one cable though, as if there is a problem troubleshooting it could be a pain.

Assuming you're using CAT 5 cabling, you'll be fine for up to around 100m lengths. I'm not sure how big your house is, but as long as you're not exceeding that length, go with whatever situation is neatest and provides available ports where you need them.

EDIT: Just to point out, if you're connecting two cables between two switches (Which I don't believe you are) and if one or both of these are unmanaged, you will run into all sorts of problems. I don't believe this is what you're trying to do though. To be safe, there is just no need to keep that second daisy chain between the two, remove it and save yourself headaches down the line.

Comment: It's not so much a matter of size, just walls as WiFi is essentially confined to a room, but that's ok then. The main thing is that there is generally a lot of network traffic from .2 to .4. With regard to unmanaged devices, are routers managed? Or are they just network appliances for gateway stuff?

Comment: @topherg Standard consumer level routers will have unmanaged switches without a doubt. This is the type of interface you'd get with a managed switch: http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/support/docs/security/nac-appliance-410/112169-nac-layer3-21.gif